IdentityServer4 stuck in `signin-oidc` and `authorize` redirect loop
We are moving our legacy system from iis to kubernetes and having problems with identityserver authentication. We have our client-facing app and identityserver in different apps but same domain e.g client.domain.com and client.domain.com/identity and this works fine on iis but for some reason on k8s I get a loop after completing the two-factor like so until I get a 400, request too large error

The identity service works fine and all the identity server URLs return fine and I can't see any error so any pointers would help. As it's a legacy system, this is identityserver4, nuget package 2.3.2 in .NET

Ensure you are using HTTPS because otherwise cookies will probably be dropped. Often these problems are due to cookie problems, especially regargarding SameSite cookies.
See my blog post here about cookie problems in ASP.NET Core https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/
The request to large seems a bit odd, perhaps use Fiddler to explore what it contains? To long URL or to large headers?

I can confirm I use https for both services and can't see any blocked cookies, I see cookies in the browser but I don't know the inner workings of identityserver enough to know which cookies I should be looking out for or not.
The bad request is because every signin-oidc keeps being made and appended with the whole identity process cookies until it gets too big.

I would check the cookies set by IdentityServer and your client Application and check the samesite cookies, some of them needs to be set to lax. I would also check the logs to see why the requests to signin-oidc fails.

The problem is I don't even know what particular cookie from IdentityServer I'm looking for to even understand what's happening. I have the logs on both service but none showing any error so it's just more confusing :(

Use a tool like Fiddler to capture the HTTPS traffic and try to follow the flow from start to the call to /signin-oidc. But yes, grocking the flow can be a challenge in the beginning. The most interesting is what happens after the call to /signin-oidc in your client. I would also disable any authorization login in the client to ensure that it is not causing the problem.
